# Countering scout harass as terran

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

This might sound like a stupid question to ask but I want to know if there's another approach to countering builder harass while I'm constructing a building.  Sure I can get another SCV to back him up but I don't want to waste two SCVs, one for scouting and another one chasing the scout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use another SCV.

That you do is factored into the balance of the game. For gosh sakes man, you have mules, it's enough money.

Edit: I believe [Mark's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5924/countering-scout-harass-as-terran/5925#5925) is wrong. There's no way to prevent a scouting worker from seeing your build with a SCV and that has nothing to with whether or not you should use a second SCV.

Comment: You assume that scouting is only done once and during the first building.  I successfully prevent early scouters from remaining in my base past the first building. At the same time I also remain in my opponents base long enough to know what sort of build he's going because so few people aggressively prevent you from scouting.

Comment: A moderator has edited my post to be more polite. Anyway, it's impossible to kill a scouting worker with another worker because all workers have the same speed. You can't catch up if they run away from you, as in, to try to scout you. Basically, it's impossible until your first marine. If you have experiences to the contrary... then it is because you're in a lower tier league where people don't pay attention to their scouts.

Comment: @Mark: I can't prevent it every time as sometimes they scout as early as your first depot is going up.

Comment: Anyway, That's the problem.  There are times when this is done so early that it causes a slight but noticeable delay when I send the other SCV out to kill the scout.  'Specially against zerg.  Next thing you know lings are coming. A friend and I even managed to do this in a 2v2 where we sent both our scouts against a terran base and effectively delayed him from his build order.

Comment: My experience is only from higher level Platinum play so I'm not experiencing what goes on in Diamond.  Just commenting from my experience

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a waste if you prevent valuable information from getting to you opponent. For instance seeing what your build is. Also you reduce the risk of a protoss player from setting up a proxy or cannon rush/containment.

Also as Terran you run the risk of them attacking your scv as it's building. you should chase him out with a second scv until you have an army unit out.